# ICN Custom Logging

Tags: logging, content-management-system, ibm-content-navigator

I have two questions related to logging

Server Side

For server side, i'm using callbacks.getLogger().logEntry(this,"methodName"). It's working fine but the log messages are written to SystemOut of websphere. Is there any way that I can wrtie it to a separate file?

Client Side I want to have logging enabled for client side and imported ecm/LoggerMixin and then used this.logInfo("Entering");. I was expecting this message to be seen on FireBug console but no luck. Also the documentation says, these logs will be stored in some trace table of ICN. Do you guys have any idea on the table name?

Regards, Manju

Answer (score 0):

Server-side you can always just use your own logging with [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or the included [java logging API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html).

Client-side you can use the built-in console to log to FireBug:

```
console.log("Entering");
```

These approaches aren't really part of the Content Navigator API, but I think they'll serve your purpose.